# SQL Select, everything that is empty or older than 1 year, doesnt work

Tags: sql

I got the following code and it throws this Error:
Date Format representation does not fullfill the requirements.

The ldate is a char. Formatted to yyyymmdd.
And now looks something like that:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ms (idk why the minutes got added but they are all zero)
Because of that i compare it to a current_timestamp, but everything i try to compare doesnt work.
Database brand is IBM.
I just want to select all data that is older than 1 year.
The code:

```
select dtkda, TO_DATE(ldate, 'YYYYMMDD') from (select dtkda, ldate from ______ where ldate is not Null and ldate not in ('',' '))
where year(current_timestamp) > year(ldate)
```

Comment: please clarify datatype of the ldate-column

Comment: What's the database brand?

Comment: Answered both questions in my question.
At least i hope so

Comment: IBM, do you mean DB2?

Comment: GETDATE() is about MS SQL Server/Sybase. I suspect in DB2 it is something different

Comment: Yes i mean DB2.
That could be yes, but what. 
First i thought prolly it is because of the ldate is not in Date format, so i tried something like that:
where ldate = ' ' or
ldate>dateadd(year,1,convert(varchar, getdate(), 112))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you add a year and not subtract.
Another thing is that there are different types of empty - it could be an empty space like you are looking for, an empty string or null.
So if you don't know what to expect there, cover all cases.
Change the where clause to:

```
where ldate in ('',' ') 
    or ldate is null
    or ldate > dateadd(year,-1,getDate())
```

there are other approached for the last part if you think these functions aren't supported (yet you didn't say that there are errors), or if you date field is of a wrong type. But then it would be best if you provide an exmaple for that.

Comment: that seemed very nice, but yes there are still errors, i think getDate ist not supported in the DB.
I found something like that:
year(current_date) - year(ldate) in (0, 1)
the problem is still, that i now have to change the ldate in a valid date format, now it is as example like "20221017" and that as varchar

Comment: @Vortox what about `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT("ldate",'YYYYMMDD')` ?

Comment: also, your approach of getting year from the date, and subtracting won't work logically as the timeframe between 2 dates in 2 consecutive years can be almost 2 years, but you will still get 1 year difference

Comment: try `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT("ldate",'YYYYMMDD') > current_date -365`